# Variable is defined but still getting undefined error

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a playbook that completes some of its tasks on the machine that the playbook is running on. I know i can use local_action for this but I am just testing if the playbook works for now. Eventually I will need to use the delegate_to. I have defined the variable and I am using delegate_to: 'variable name' but I am getting this error. : " fatal [target node]: FAILED! => { msg":  "'variablename' is undefined. Below is my playbook:

```
name: Create certs
gather_facts: true
vars:
  master: "{{ nameofhost }}"

tasks:
 - name: Run command
   shell: Command to run
   delegate_to: "{{ master }}"
```

Comment: master is undefined because hostanme is undefined too. You need to define hostname var.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. So I was not running the hostname command in that part of code I just wrote the name of the host i want to use. Sorry I should have been more clear. But if i did want to define hostname like you said i would just put it in the same section where I am defining my host like this: " hostname: "{{ hostname }}" or is there different syntax to do that.

Comment: If you're looking to run on the master, you can just use `localhost`: `delegate_to: localhost`. In the case of your playbook as you have shown, the `nameofhost` variable isn't set anywhere that you show, so naturally it will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target your play to a target hosts of an inventory

````
name: Create certs
gather_facts: true
hosts: target_hosts
vars:
  master: "{{ nameofhost }}"
tasks:
 - name: Run command
   shell: Command to run
   delegate_to: "{{ master }}"

``` 

Your inventory files may look like that:

    [target_hosts]
    master ansible_host=your_master_dns_or_ip


And then ansible can target that inventory group and then reduce the task scope to master host. Or you can just use the localhost as target.
````